# how to set default focus?

Tags: jquery, html

Now one Submit button is the default focused control. but I need to set the default focus to another imagebutton.

Here is the sample image "button"

```
<img style="vertical-align: top; border-style: none;"                                                   src="IconAdd.jpg" id="imbAdd" onclick="javascript:Add();" title="Click to Add" style="cursor:hand;" />
```

But i use

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#imbAdd").focus();}
```

It doesn't work.

I hope i'm clear. i need to implement when I press Enter, i can trigger "click" event for this image "button".

Thanks

---

Solution: 
I use 
`<input type="image" id="imbAdd" onclick="addEntry();return false;">`
.. instead of the image link. and set 
`<form id="form1" defaultButton="imbAdd">`
but this type button will cause submit which is not what I want. so i need to add "return false;" at the end "addEntry()" to make sure the image button will never cause any undesired submit.

Comment: Focus doesn't do what you think it does. If you explain your goal a bit better someone may be able to help, but you are currently barking up the wrong tree, I think.

Answer (score 5):

since HTML5:

```
<button type="button" autofocus>
Click Me!
</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set focus to every element.

Its better you write a function that will be triggered on the keydown event and check for "Enter" key and the trigger the click event of the image.

in your keyup event check for this

```
var kCode = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which); 

if (kCode == 13) 
{ 
   // its the enter key pressed
}
```

Comment: thanks,i got from MSDN that there indeed exists "defaultFocus" and "defualtButton" for form tag.
Anyway, thanks. your solution is an good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

There's something called tabindex that works on a variety of browsers. I use it to skip over images in a captcha for form focus. Its a first class attribute. It may give you the behavior you want if you reorder the tabindex/focus order of the two buttons.

```
<input type="text" name="test_field_1" tabindex=2></input>
<input type="text" name="test_field_1" tabindex=1></input>
```

Josh

Comment: thanks, but this is not what I need for the issue..it's set now. please see the comment below